# NodeJS HTTPs request returns Socket Hang up

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

```
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");

const options = {
  hostname: "en.wikipedia.org",
  port: 443,
  path: "/wiki/George_Washington",
  method: "GET",
  // ciphers: 'DES-CBC3-SHA'
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  let responseBody = "";
  console.log("Response started");
  console.log(`Server Status: ${res.statusCode} `);
  console.log(res.headers);
  res.setEncoding("UTF-8");

  res.once("data", (chunk) => {
    console.log(chunk);
  });

  res.on("data", (chunk) => {
    console.log(`--chunk-- ${chunk.length}`);
    responseBody += chunk;
  });

  res.on("end", () => {
    fs.writeFile("gw.html", responseBody, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Downloaded file");
    });
  });
});

req.on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("Request problem", err);
});
```

returns

```
// Request problem { Error: socket hang up
//     at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:330:15)
//     at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:423:23)
//     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:165:20)
//     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1101:12)
//     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

Comment: The wikipedia server closed the connection to you. There are various reasons, one might be a timeout or an invalid request, try to request this url manually to see what might go wrong.

Comment: I curled the URL and it works fine. tried all suggestions from the "duplicate" question , none works. I also saw this: https://github.com/request/request/issues/2047 Do you mind reopening please?

Comment: by the way the question shown as duplicate is different; the poster is asking to explain what an error message means, I am just trying to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Add `req.end()` in the last line

Comment: @JonasW. your comment should be an answer then :) if you want add and I'll accept thanks!

Comment: @samuel well do you have a good one? The one I voted for was not explaining this case

Comment: @samuel yep but it is the 10th answer on the page, probably no one will ever read it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`http.request()` opens a new tunnel to the server. It returns a Writable stream which allows you to send data to the server, and the callback gets called with the stream that the server responds with. Now the error you encountered (`ECONNRESET`) basically means that the tunnel was closed. That usually happens when an error occured on a low level (very unlikely) or the tunnel timed out because no data was received. In your case the server only responded when you sent something to it, even if it was an empty package, so all you have to do is to end the stream, causing it to get flushed as an empty packet to the server, which causes it to respond:

```
 req.end();
```

You might want to have a look at the [`request`](https://github.com/request/request) package which allows you to avoid dealing with such low-level things.

Comment: you mean https://github.com/request/request ? Yeah, of course, I'd never use the API on such a low level, now I'm just exploring it for experimentation purposes :)

Comment: @george exactly, and thats a lehitimate reason to use it :)

Comment: FYI from the future, the request package was deprecated in 2020.